# What is the best strategy to migrate the members of my ham-related Yahoo!Group to ham.se?

Tags: discussion, support

I am the "moderator-owner" of the [Windom Antenna Yahoo!Group](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/windom_antenna/join).

I have been longing to move that Yahoo!Group to a more "mature" Q&A site like ham.stackexchange.com.

What would be the best strategy to do so?

I have noticed that Yahoo! accounts can be used to sign in to StackExchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the site, and I'm glad to hear you find this site a worthwhile successor to your own community! I hope you have great success with it.

I'm not sure if there's much of a *strategy* beyond encouraging people to start using this site. Yes, if the participants already have a Yahoo! account, they will be able to it as their Open ID to log into *this* site (one less username/password they have to remember).

But we don't really have any provisions for importing content from other systems, nor would that really work particularly well. The question/answer format of a Stack Exchange site works somewhat differently from a traditional discussion-style Q&A, so the content does not lend itself to copying *en masse.* It's better to simply ask people to check out the site and start asking their questions… and to improve the answers with their experience and expertise. If there is a particularly *interesting* post you would like preserved from a previous forum, certainly you can re-ask the question within the context of *this* site and encourage folks to contribute their knowledge here. Everything here is licensed under Creative Commons for reuse, so anything posted here is designed to make the Internet a better place in general… for everyone's benefit.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion I could make that might help is to simply subscribe the group to the weekly newsletter posts from this site. That will help encourage them to use the new site, and give them a flavor for what kinds of questions are being asked here. Aside from that, just post a really good review with some good sample questions, etc, and have at it!